# How to stream trades for all spot trading pairs on binance using websockets in python

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I am trying to stream every single trade for all spot trading pairs on the Binance exchange in real time using web sockets. I have searched for a websocket endpoint to do so and have not found one.
I have tried making a call to the "***exchange info***" endpoint and getting all trading pairs. Then from there I filtered out the ones that had a trading status of halted and the pairs that didn't allow spot trading. Then I passed these trading pairs which were made lower cased and abbreviated with the proper "@trade" to show I wanted trade info. When I sent this request to the server Binance didn't respond. I have left my code below for you to reproduce my problem:

```
import ssl
import websocket
import _thread as thread
import re
import ast
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)
    message = json.loads(message)
    message = message.get('data')
    
    try:
        symbol = message.get("s")
        timestamp = message.get("T")
        price = message.get("p")
        quantity = message.get("q")
        is_buyer_maker = message.get("m")

        if is_buyer_maker:
            taker = "sell"
        else:
            taker = "buy"

        data = {"symbol": symbol,
                "timestamp": timestamp,
                "price": price,
                "quantity": quantity,
                "taker": taker}

        print(data)
    except:
        pass


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### Binance Closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        print(logon_msg)
        ws.send(logon_msg)
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    content = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo").json()
    content = content.get("symbols")

    symbols = []
    for thing in content:
        if thing.get("status") == "TRADING" and thing.get("isSpotTradingAllowed") == True:
            symbols.append(thing.get("symbol"))

    symbols = [i.lower() + "@trade" for i in symbols]

    logon_msg = {"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": symbols,"id": 1}
    logon_msg = json.dumps(logon_msg)

    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=trade",
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close,
                                on_open=on_open)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @CoderBang No I didn't, I think I just used a list of cryptocurrency trading pairs. This was a long time ago and I might have forgotten what I did.